# DDD Stateless Services and Constructor Injection

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, domainservices, onion-architecture

In Domain Driven Design literature it is often said that domain services should be stateless.

I believe the reason for this is because service calls should represent single units of work.  There shouldn't be any service state which multiple service methods would use.

I break this rule in my service architecture so that I can constructor inject all the relevant repositories required in the service.  Example:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

    public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository { get; set; }

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserRepository userRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        UserRepository = userRepository;
        CustomerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public User RegisterNewUser(...)
    {
        // Perform relevant domain logic
    }

    // ...
}
```

In order for me to use constructor injection on the `UserService`, I would need to have state (properties) so that the service methods have access to the relevant repositories and such.

Although I hope to design the individual service methods as isolated units of work, I cannot necessarily prevent that from happening.

**How could I architecture domain services so that they are stateless?**  Is this even necessary?

**EDIT:**

**Eric Evans** in [Domain-driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215):

> When a significant process or transformation in the domain is not a
>   natural responsibility of an ENTITY or VALUE OBJECT, add an operation
>   to the model as standalone interface declared as a SERVICE. Define the
>   interface in terms of the language of the model and make sure the
>   operation name is part of the UBIQUITOUS LANGUAGE. Make the SERVICE
>   **stateless**.

**Vaughn Vernon** also recommends stateless services in his book [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577).

Comment: If you want the services to become stateless, you should pass in the dependencies through method arguments, but that would be quite hideous and promotes those dependencies from implementation details to part of the contract.

Comment: Yes, that would not be fun.  It would also mean that I would have to inject the relevant repositories in the application layer and/or MVC controllers.

Comment: I believe that Evens meant something different than you think. I think he compares the state of a service with the state of a domain object. A domain object will clearly have state and change its state during its lifetime. A service won't -or shouldn't- change state and I think that that is what he means by 'stateless'. I think it is impossible to make a service completely stateless, since it will always run in some sort of statefull context; an UnitOfWork for instance, or a DB transaction. The service will always be effected by this, whether you inject dependencies or use service location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get close to your goal is to inject an IOC container into your service class then override your property get methods to resolve an instance of the necessary class. Your new class would look something like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork 
  { 
    get{return container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()}
  }
  private IUnityContainer container {get;set;}

  public UserService(IUnityContainer container )
  {
    this.container = container;
  }

  public User RegisterNewUser(User user)
  {
     //Domain logic
  }

}
```

Your service class now has a dependency on an IOC container which is not a good thing, but if you are trying to get closer to a stateless service, this would do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This seems like the best option but I definitely do not want to create a dependency in my domain layers to an IOC container.  Is it even necessary to have stateless services?

Comment: Looking at your code, I am assuming that you are making a web app data access layer, so the main concern would be handling multi-threading. If you configure your application so each user gets her own instance of IUserService then it does not matter. If users are sharing the same service, then you could run into concurrency issues (i.e. IUnitofWork.Save() is called when another thread is part way through a call). In this case the solution I created could help by allowing users to share the same IUserService instance, but get their own DbContexts through the IOC container.

Comment: This is seriously a bad idea. This is the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: Also note that this doesn't solve the state problem at all, since from a state perspective there's very little difference between injecting dependencies through he constructor and resolving them from the container inside the method. Most of your services will be stateless,  but at runtime depend upon a Unit of Work that will hold the needed state. That same UoW is used and the amount of state stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you confuse having properties with having state.

`UserService` is a service. It only has readonly (*please remove the setters*) properties that are stateless services, such as `IUserRepository`. This makes `UserService` itself a stateless service.

Yes, we could even add a higher-level service on top, that has an `IUserService` as one of its components. That service, too, would be stateless.

Why, you ask?

The purpose (or at least *a* purpose) of the statelessness is to allow Inversion of Control: we relinquish control over *what instances we get* to the outside. If someone else is controlling what instances we get, then those instances had better be stateless! What if we get the same instance that another class is getting, and we both start altering its state? The outcome would be indeterminate.

True, this problem is avoided if our services have no properties at all - like `UserRepository`, perhaps. Notice also that it is *equally well avoided* when a higher-level service, such as `UserService`, exclusively has readonly properties of such services, because there is nothing to assign. We can rest assured that the injected service will always behave correctly, as there is no state in its hierarchy for it to depend on.